# Isolating an existing RS485 tranceiver

Tags: isolation, rs485, modbus

I have a heat pump with an RS485 interface. Via a simple RS485 chip. No isolated interface, no isolated power supply to it.

I want to add a power meter at 400+ meter to it and want to properly isolate the heat pump from that line. Speed is 9600Baud. Is there an isolator solution that comes to mind? I could not get further than converting RS485 to Tx and Rx, and then take a properly isolated RS485 chip as the interface. I think this is overdoing it (1), but I also hadn’t figured out how to do the Driver Enable of both ICs (2). The latter made me think that I want to understand how to do it as simple as possible.

What would be the simplest way isolating bidirectionally used Half duplex RS485?

Comment: To what device you want to connect it, a PC? And with what interface? E.g. isolated USB RS485 adapters are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Isolated RS485 Repeater is probably the simplest solution for your job.

Comment: I was looking at a simple IC, not a device. Like you can isolate SPI with an isolation chip